# How do you populate information from a user's AD profile to a list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, ad

We have a custom list for user access request....as it stands now,  they have to select the employee name and supervisor from the(ppl picker) fields, and select the following from a drop down (job title, location, department etc...)

Mnagement wanted to be able to select an employee name(ppl picker) from the custom list and automatically generate his/her supervisor, job title, location, department (pretty much pull all the information related to this employee from AD)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using the profileproperties class from the Javascript object model

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-retrieve-user-profile-properties-by-using-the-javascript-object-model-in

Answer (score 0):

As Addition to Erin's answer , you can also use infoPath forms , and retrieve and populate users information from user profile using `UserProfileService` service 

[How to Create an InfoPath Form to Auto Populate User Data](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/)